# Span inside th width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have table with *span* element in *th*.
I want span width to match th, but actually it fills the entire row :(.

My code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < testInfoFieldsNames.length; i++) {
       title = testInfoFieldsNames[i].toLowerCase();

       th = $('<th></th>');
       span = $('<span></span>').addClass('cell-container').text(title);
       th.append( span );
    }

    tableHeader.append(th);
```

css:

```
.cell-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

How can I set span width to fill *th* only?

Comment: Your span looks suspiciously like a `div`

Comment: Thats a `div` inside variable `span`, You sure thats right?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you beauty!

Comment: you are right, it was changed during my attempts.. thank you.

Comment: @rkfred please try the below solution or just replace the CSS I think  it will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should give th a style like:

```
th{
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this indeed resolved the issue! Do you know to explain why?

Comment: Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any, or otherwise relative to the initial containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any other margins.

Comment: @rkfred [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position] u can find answer in this webpage

Answer (score 0):

Please try this I think this will work for you.

please check this example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cqfgefy1/)

```
    for (var i = 0; i < testInfoFieldsNames.length; i++) {
       title = testInfoFieldsNames[i].toLowerCase();

       th = $('<th><span class="cell-container">'+title+'</span></th>');
    }

    tableHeader.append(th);
```

CSS

```
span.cell-container {
  display: block;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works just like the above code.. it's indeed append 'th's with 'span's. but span still fill entire row instead of cell..

Comment: @rkfred The problem is with CSS position tag please remove it or replace it by "position: relative;"

Comment: @rkfred  its working please edit the CSS and try and for more detail go the attached link

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed working. But now I have new problem: I want text-overflow to be elipsis, and this works with position absolute........  Do you have any idea how to solve both?

Comment: @rkfred Please mask the above solution as  answer So that it can help others and please vote up if this really helps you.

Comment: I cannot take this solution as it conflicts my needs, and my question is still not resolved. I only can vote it up..

Answer (score -1):

Tag 'span' is inline element. It does not have width and height. 
You should use 'div' or set following property

```
display:block;
```

Comment: Thanks! I indeed uses this property in my css, but span width still fills the entire row..